# Obtaining number of moves in Towers of Hanoi

Tags: java, towers-of-hanoi

Given this method,

```
public static String solve(int n, String start, String middle, String end)
```

I want to return the number of moves. I can somewhat obtain this with this code:

```
public static String solve(int n, String start, String middle, String end) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return Integer.toString(1);
    }
    return solve(n - 1, start, end, middle) + solve(n - 1, middle, start, end) + 1;
}
```

but when I give 1 disk the answer is 1, when I give 2 disk the answer is 111, when I give 3 disk the answer is 1111111, 4 is 111111111111111, and so on. The number of 1's in each string represents a move but I do not want the 1's, I want 1, 3, 7, 15, and so on. How can I alter this code to let me get the latter numbers?

Comment: If you want result to be the *number* of moves, why is the return type a `String`? Wouldn't `int` be better? -- Since you never use `start`, `middle`, and `end` for anything, why are they there?

Answer (score 2):

Three possible solutions:

- Change `solve` to return int; change first `return` to `return 1;`
- Leave `solve` alone, but capture the resulting `String` in a variable `s` and print `s.length()` rather than `s` itself;
- Throw away `solve` and just use the formula `Math.pow(2, n) - 1;`

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the 2nd method. I have tried and it's not changing anything

Comment: `Sting s = solve(5,"","",""); System.out.println(s.length());`